# My future is not execute using FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use FutureBuilder but i'm countering an issue, my future is called but not executed. And i couldn't understand why. Does someone has an idea why ?

This is my code:

```
class TesPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TesPageState createState() => _TesPageState();
}

class _TesPageState extends State<TesPage> {
  Future<String> future;
  Future<String> futureFunction() async {
    try {
      await text(); 
      return "Test"; // this is never called
    } catch (e) {
      return e.toString();
    }
  }

  @override
  @mustCallSuper
  void initState() {
    future = futureFunction();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: new FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: future,
        builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
          // returning a widget based on the future
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you !

**Update**
fix my code example

Comment: Seems that your code is not valid. Can you please double check?

Comment: Where do you use await?

Comment: inside the future

Comment: I can not confirm this behaviour. Since I do not know whats the code in your text() method I inserted the following line: await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)); With this the future returns as expected after one second

Comment: I fixed my issue, the problem was that i was getting the context inside the FutureFunction. Thank you for your help @SebastianK

Answer (score 0):

You are not properly waiting for a `Future` to be resolved.
I suggest you to do the following way:

```
class TesPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TesPageState createState() => _TesPageState();
}

class _TesPageState extends State<TesPage> {
//Future<String> future;
  Future<String> futureFunction() async {
    try {
      await text(); 
      return "Test"; // this is never called
    } catch (e) {
      return e.toString();
    }
  }

  //@override
  //@mustCallSuper
  //void initState() {
  //  future = futureFunction();
  //  super.initState();
  //}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: new FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: futureFunction(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
            // returning a widget based on the future 
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've commented the unused statements and variables
This way the `FutureBuilder` will invoke the `futureFunction` and wait for its result.

Be aware of the states `snapshot` can be in, check [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot-class.html) for complete informations.

Usually you can just check if `snapshot.hasData` or not, but the class offers you more information about the status of the `async` computation (aka the `futureFunction` in this case).

Comment: The problem with your solution it that while you call the future this way it will be recalled each time the build function is runn as it is mentioned in the future builder doc

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. You could cache the result of the future in a state variable